# Stored Procedure returns old value in ef core

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API. I am using raw SQL with a stored procedure to compute some values:

```
private TestContext context;

public TestRepository(TestContext tContext)
{
     context = tContext;
}    

public IEnumerable<test> GetTests(User user)
{
    return context.tests.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.test_GETALL {0}", user.code).ToList();
}
```

When I insert new record into my table, the result must be changed, but this code returns old values. How I fix this problem?

Comment: do you have new data in the db?

Comment: How are you calling the API? though jquery ajax or what method? It sound like the request is cached. You can verify by running a profiler trace to verify the database is being hit.

Comment: @Sampath yes, after inserting new data I call stored procedure again. but it returns old value.

Comment: @firste I call API using HttpClient

Comment: you can use `SQL profiler` to identity whether your `SP` is running on the `SQL server` or not ? can you see that ?

Comment: @Sampath I execute SQL profiler. when I call API, my SP runs too. but result in API is the older one.

Comment: what happened when you run the `SP` directly on the SQL server ? what is the result ?

Comment: @Sampath its result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If TestContext is connected to EF, than that's the problem, or otherwise you may have your transaction badly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this myself.

Check your **startup.cs** and make sure that service and repositories **are not** `.AddSingleton`.

These will need to be changed to `.AddScoped` (You might be able to use `.AddTransient` too)

```
services.AddSingleton<IYourService, YourService>(); //Needs to be AddScoped
services.AddSingleton<IYourRepository, YourRepository>(); //Also needs to be AddScoped
```

If you need more detail, here is [my SO question that I believe relates to your situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705137/stored-procedure-returns-old-data/41771867#41771867).

Hope this helps!