# Stored Procedure returns old data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, geolocation, asp.net-core

I'm very confused. I'm using EF CORE. I'm hoping this has happened for others in older Entity Frameworks.

I'm having a problem whereby I am providing **different** postcodes which are converted into lat longs.

```
@gLat nvarchar(50),
@gLong nvarchar(50)

DECLARE @Location geography = geography::Point(@gLat, @gLong,4326)
```

however the "Distance" field is returning the same distance.

```
cast(@Location.STDistance(Location) / 1609.344 AS float) AS 'Distance' 
--Always returns the same distance AS THE LAST QUERY when back in C#
```

eg) if the postcode **XXXXXX0** is given, the returned distance is 1.5
if a new query is called with postcode 
**YYYYYY1**, the distance returned is still 1.5 .......

I wondered if at first it was because of the scope, but it is set to AddScope which means a new context is create for each request.

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository, Repository>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

It turns out that my service, in startup.cs, was AddSingleton.

```
services.AddSingleton<IPersonService, PersonService>(); //Needs to be AddScoped
services.AddSingleton<IPersonRepository, PersonRepository>(); //Also needs to be AddScoped
```

This wouldn't have worked as singleton will only be created once and will be the same instance for every http request.

What we need is a new instance for every http request.

Also, make sure that the services' scope is the same as the repositories.

For more information you can go to this page [What is the difference between services.AddTransient, service.AddScope and service.AddSingleton methods in Asp.Net Core 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138100/what-is-the-difference-between-services-addtransient-service-addscope-and-servi)

Please make any amendments to this if it's not all correct!

Hope this helps =)